# java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"

Tags: jenkins, plugins, proxy

Unable to download plugins in jenkins Gave correct proxy details

Refer screenshot[Tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBQcx.png)

Comment: Is your jenkins instance running behind a proxy server ?

Comment: Yes its running behind proxy server

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of Manage Plugin > Advance Tab?